# Postgres Dynamic Query Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I need to create a function that will run a query and return the results with the table name and the column name being arugments given to the function. I currently have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qa_scf(tname character varying, cname character varying)
RETURNS SETOF INT AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tname WHERE cname !='AK' AND cname!='CK';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
```

This gives me the error "Relation 'tname' des not exist" when run. I'm new to function creating for Postgres, so any help is appreciated. I feel like the return int is wrong, but I don't know what else to put to make it return all columns for the rows returned. Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot use a variable in place of an identifier like that.  You need to do it with dynamic queries.  It will look something like this:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(tname) 
        || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(cname) || ' NOT IN (''AK'',''CK'');'
INTO result_var;
```

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.1 or above, you can use [the format() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289939/398670) which makes constructing this string much easier.

Comment: What should I declare the result_var as?

Comment: Never interpolate values into dynamic sql statements without using the appropriate quote_FOO() function or you open the door to injection attacks.

Comment: This is an internal facing database.

Comment: "Internal facing" means anyone with access to your network can own your database.

Comment: @debenhur Yup, agreed; also, "internal facing" doesn't mean ACCIDENTAL injection of a problematic identifier won't horribly break things.

Comment: Just an FYI, I don't recommend doing this AT ALL.  Dynamic queries that take table/column parameters are many times an indication of a bad design.

Comment: @dbenhur: If I'm reading the documentation correctly, the %L and %I format specifications in 9.1's format() function server the same purpose as quote_literal() and quote_identifier() and, yes, these methods should be used if one must do dynamic queries.

Comment: @MatthewWood that's correct, they serve the same purpose, but make for somewhat more concise and readable code.

Answer (score 19):

Table and column names can not be specified as parameters or variables without dynamically constructing a string to execute as a dynamic statement. Postgres has excellent introductory documentation about [executing dynamic statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). It's important to properly quote identifiers and literals with `quote_ident()` or `quote_literal()`. The [format()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function helps clean up dynamic sql statement construction. Since you declare the function to return `SETOF INTEGER`, you should select the integer field you want, not `*`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION qa_scf(tname text, cname text)
RETURNS SETOF INTEGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
    'SELECT the_integer_field FROM %I WHERE %I NOT IN (%L,  %L)',
                                   tname,   cname,    'AK', 'CK'
  );
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: How do I make it return all of the columns?

Comment: You can `SELECT *` and declare `RETURNS SETOF RECORD`.  Then the consumer has to understand the record tuple. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

Comment: And how do I give it the column definition list? Is there any way to dynamically pull this?

Comment: Read that wiki link in more detail, it explains how to interpret a record result with the consumer. If you're really returning polymorphic results, that gets into more introspection and dynamic metaprogramming -- are you sure you want to go there? Go open another question exploring those issues.

Comment: You should ideally be using `EXECUTE ... USING` in your example to handle those two insertions into the WHERE clause as query parameters. In your particular case it doesn't matter as they're hardcoded, but it's a good idea in general.

Comment: @j.gardner117 See `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

Comment: @j.gardner117 You can also return a `hstore` instead of a `RECORD`; a hstore is basically a dynamic hash table. It won't perform as well and doesn't have strong data typing, but is easily dynamically introspected. I think some changes were made in PL/PgSQL recently to make it work better with dynamic RECORDs where column names etc are unknown until runtime, but I don't recall the details; check the documentation.