# PostgreSQL - dynamic value as table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dynamic-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postgres Dynamic Query Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function)

I wish to use the returned string from the query below as a table name for other query.

```
SELECT 'backup_' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

as you can see it returns a string. I wish to use it as an input for another query, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE (SELECT 'backup_' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')) 
AS * SELECT FROM backup
```

Can it be done? Any clue how?

Comment: I have solution that do not apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function but interesting for this issue : SELECT '"backup_' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') || '"' AS tname;
\gset

CREATE TABLE :tname AS SELECT * FROM backup;

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You will need to use the [PL/PgSQL `EXECUTE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html), via a `DO` block or PL/PgSQL function (`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ... LANGUAGE plpgsql`). Dynamic SQL is not supported in the ordinary SQL dialect used by PostgreSQL, only in the procedural PL/PgSQL variant.

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I AS SELECT * FROM backup', 'backup_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The [`format(...)` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)'s `%I` and `%L` format-specifiers do proper identifier and literal quoting, respectively.

For literals I recommend using `EXECUTE ... USING` rather than `format(...)` with `%L`, but for identifiers like table/column names the format `%I` pattern is a nice concise alternative to verbose `quote_ident` calls.

Comment: Will the name automatically be quoted if it contains special characters? I'm not really a PostgreSQL user, but it seems doubtful that a simple FORMAT() function would be clever enough to do that.

Comment: @AndriyM The `%I` interpolation placeholder in the [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function is specifically for postgres identifiers and will safely quote the supplied value.

Comment: @dbenhur: Oh, good, thanks. Nice solution then, Craig! (apparently :)