# Inserting data from DatagridView error

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio, npgsql

I've got

```
string insert_cmd_str;

using (conn_server)
{
    using (NpgsqlCommand insert_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
    {
        insert_cmd.Connection = conn_server;
        conn_server.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            insert_cmd_str = "insert into @table values (" +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].FormattedValue + "', " +
                                 "'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].FormattedValue + "')";
            insert_cmd.CommandText = insert_cmd_str;
            insert_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", "table");


            MessageBox.Show(insert_cmd.CommandText + Environment.NewLine +
                            insert_cmd.Parameters["@db"].Value);

            insert_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn_server.Close();
    }
}
```

And I get an error:

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "("

I've added the `MessageBox` to check the command text just before it executes and it seems to be good. If I post the same text into PG admin it executes the command without the error.

The command text is:

```
insert into @table values ('425', '10-31-2016 00:00:00', 'False', '', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'pas_kosmetologus', 'Skambutis', '237')
```

The value of `@table` is `table`.
I can't figure out were the error comes from. I've even tried deleting both parenthesis from the command text but it still throws the same error.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Your table is called table? thats a keyword that can cause you issues.

Comment: Not really. I've just changed it here to simplify it. The actual name of the table it needs to insert data into is based on the user of the application.

Comment: It may be that the insert statement expects the columns first, e.g. `insert into (column1, ...) values (value1, ...)`

Comment: For now it's vizitai_test. I don't think that could cause the error.

Comment: @Martynas Did you check it?

Comment: @rbr94 I've added the names of the columns into the string. Still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't support parameterizing table or column names - you'll have to either concatenate these in into your string (but beware of SQL injection), or write a plpgsql. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13289939/640325 for an example.

Regardless, concatenating in the values from your datagrid leaves you wide open to SQL injection, consider using parameters there.

Comment: I've changed the table name from a parameter to a string and it works.