# PostgreSQL - can I use functions return name as view name

Tags: postgresql

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getViewName ()
RETURNS text LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $name$
DECLARE
    name text ;
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'test_schema.backup_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyymmdd')  into name ;
    RETURN name ;
END ; $name$;
```

which creates a function successfully.

```
=> select getViewName();
          getviewname
-------------------------------
 test_schema.backup_20190108
(1 row)
```

but when I try this:

```
=> create or replace view getViewName() AS select * from test_schema.backup ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: create or replace view getViewName() AS select * from ...
```

Can I not use the return of the function as my view name?

I don't want to use a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289304/postgresql-dynamic-value-as-table-name), because in reality code will look like :

```
create or replace view getViewName() AS select
.....
```

where .... is over 1k lines of code and I don't want to put it inside a format.

Are there any alternative?

**Edit:**

I tried creating the temporary view with a fixed name.

Then do something like:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format( 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW %I '
                ' AS SELECT * FROM test_schema.mytemp_view', getViewName()  ) ;
END ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

But then the problem is that I cannot drop mytemp_view since the new dynamic view is dependent on it.

Comment: Create the view with a fixed name and then use it to do select in dynamic create statement if the query size is your problem.

Comment: @RomanKonoval can you check my edit? Did you mean that?