# Dynamically passing db and table names using stored procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure in `PostgreSQL` which will first check on the basis of `'ID'` if the data is present in the given table. If yes, then move it to some other table and insert the newest record in the given table name. I have a written a stored procedure where I tried it with hard-coded values and it works as I need but when I am trying to make it generic i.e creating variables and then passing those variables inside the queries then it throws an error. I referred below `SO links` and [official documentation link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and was able to modify my stored procedure:

1. [First SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289304/postgresql-dynamic-value-as-table-name)
2. [Second SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289304/postgresql-dynamic-value-as-table-name)

Below is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE compareDups(ab integer, b json, tablename varchar)
AS $$
DECLARE 
  actualTableName varchar := 'testing.'||tablename;
  histTableName varchar:= actualTableName ||'_hist';
  job_id Integer:=0;
BEGIN --<<<< HERE
  EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM '||actualTableName||' WHERE id =$1' INTO job_id USING ab;
  -- if there is data for id in the table then perform below operations
  IF job_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I as select * from %L where id = $1',histTableName,actualTableName) USING ab;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('DELETE FROM %I where id = $1',actualTableName) USING ab;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  -- if id is not present then create a new record in the actualTable
  ELSE    
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  END IF;

END; --<<<< END HERE
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, while `creating variables` I have used just `EXECUTE` option and while `calling queries` I have used `EXECUTE FORMAT(...)` option.

And when I try to call this, I am getting below error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "testing.sampletesting_hist" as select * from 't...
                                                    ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO "testing.sampletesting_hist" as select * from 'testing.sampletesting' where id = $1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function comparedups(integer,json,character varying) line 10 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

What am I missing over here?

Comment: What you are missing is that "testing.sampletesting_hist" should be "testing"."sampletesting_hist" Also this 'testing.sampletesting' is not valid. Identifiers need to be double quoted.

Comment: yeah I got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I would like to answer my own question maybe it can help someone like me. I was able to fix the above code by modifying the `actualtablename` string where I was setting up the `schema name` too. So, I added a `SET` statement inside the procedure for setting up schema names where the intended operations need to take place and it worked for me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE compareDups(ab integer, b json, tablename varchar)
AS $$
DECLARE 
  actualTableName varchar := tablename;
  histTableName varchar:= actualTableName ||'_hist';
  job_id Integer:=0;
BEGIN --<<<< HERE
  SET search_path to testing; -- Set the schema name
  EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM '||actualTableName||' WHERE id =$1' INTO job_id USING ab;
  -- if there is data for id in the table then perform below operations
  IF job_id IS NOT NULL THEN
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I select * from %I where id = $1',histTableName,actualTableName) USING ab;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('DELETE FROM %I where id = $1',actualTableName) USING ab;
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  -- if id is not present then create a new record in the actualTable
  ELSE    
      EXECUTE FORMAT('INSERT INTO %I values($1,$2)',actualTableName) USING ab,b;
  END IF;

END; --<<<< END HERE
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Somehow, this procedure is getting stored under the `public` schema. So, while calling it I have to use the below commands:

```
set search_path to public;
call compareDups(12,'{"name":"CTTT"}','sampletesting');
```

Comment: Well you did not schema qualify the ```PROCEDURE``` name so it got created in the first schema in the ```search_path```.  Setting the search_path in the procedure only works inside the procedure. Explicit is better then implicit if you want an object to be assigned to a schema then name it that way e.g. my_schema.compareDups. Or do the ```SET search_path``` immediately before the ```CREATE```

Comment: So you mean I should specify the set search_path command before creating procedure so that it would be creating under that schema?

Comment: Yes. Though the better option is to do ```CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing.compareDups(...)``` Then there is no guessing.

Comment: Yeah let me try this. Thanks @Adrian ;)