# How to execute dynamic query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to execute dynamic query using PostgreSQL. I have a function with three parameters and need to suffix that parameters with some variables(to make view name) and need to retrieve rows from that variables(view) and return the result.

**Example**

```
create or replace function testing(abc varchar,def varchar,ghi varchar)
returns setof record as
$BODY$
Declare
      temptable1 varchar :='temp1_';
      temptable2 varchar :='temp2_';
      viewname varchar :='view_';
Body
      temptable1 := temptable1||abc;
      temptable2 := temptable2||def;
      viewname := viewname||ghi;

      execute 'Drop table if exists'||temptable1;
      execute 'Drop table if exists'||temptable2;

      WITH cm
      AS
      (
      SELECT "ssno","rlno",
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(Partition by "ssno" Order By "rlno"     )FoundIn
      From viewname;
      )
    SELECT DISTINCT * INTO temptable1
    FROM cm
    WHERE FoundIn > 1;

    SELECT DISTINCT cr."ssno", cdr."rlno"
        INTO temptable2
        FROM temptable1 l1
        INNER JOIN viewname cr on l1."rlno" = cr."rlno"
        ORDER BY "rlno";

    /* Need to result should be display for below query */
    SELECT DISTINCT  cr.ssno AS Nos, cr.rlno, FoundIn,cr.Name, cr.Address,
from temptable1 l1
inner join viewname cr on l1.rlno = cr.rlno
order by "rlno"

end;
$BODY$
Language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to return the query? Prefix it with `RETURN QUERY`.

Comment: @Nick Barmes, I am just confusing about how to execute WITH and SELECT statements and return the result of last SELECT statement. Shall I use EXECUTE or just RETURN QUERY before the SELECT statement.

Comment: Just `RETURN QUERY` ([example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e0fe/2)). You only need `EXECUTE` when your query is stored in a string.

Comment: @Nick Barnes, I am getting notice that table does not exists. Not proceeding for next step from drop table.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your code closely enough. Table names cannot be variables in ordinary queries; you need to build all your queries as strings and `EXECUTE` them. Returning the result is simple, e.g. `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || tablename;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres Dynamic Query Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function)

Comment: @DanielVérité, The above query taking too much time for execution for 54k records. I have added index also.

Comment: @NickBarnes,  The above query taking too much time for execution for 54k records. I have added index also.