# Placeholder in PostgreSQL sql file

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables that are created in the same way (same columns, indexes, etc.)
I would like to have one sql file for creating them all without duplicating the create statements.

Is there a way to use some kind of placeholder in sql file which would be substituted when executing the sql file with a parameter?

For example I would like to have below sql statement:

```
drop table if exists schema.%PLACEHOLDER%;
create table schema.%PLACEHOLDER%(id text, data text);
```

And execute such script with:

```
psql -f mysqlfile.sql -magic_parameter my_desired_table_name
```

Is this possible when executing PostgreSQL sql files, or maybe other way to achieve the same (except using sed)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres Dynamic Query Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sincr you are using `psql`, you can use variables as follows:

```
drop table if exists schema.:placeholder;
```

The invocation is:

```
psql -f mysqlfile.sql -v placeholder=table_name
```