# concatenate the contents of two columns of the same table produces a name with double quotes

Tags: postgresql

the situation.
I'm producing a function, and part of it needs to get the name of each table by concatenating schemaname.tablename to iterate.
part of the code:

the part that it´s producing the error:

```
select schemaname||'.'||tablename as otra from pg_tables where schemaname = 'vigano' and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
```

The hole function is this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION yield_summary()
RETURNS TABLE (
   promedio double precision,
   minimo double precision,
   maximo double precision
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   v_sql text := '';
   v_sep text := '';
   v_tab text;
BEGIN
   FOR v_tab IN
      select schemaname||'.'||tablename as otra from pg_tables where schemaname = 'vigano' and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
   LOOP
      v_sql := v_sql || v_sep ||
         format(
            'select round(avg(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as promedio, round(min(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as minimo, round(max(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as maximo 
             FROM %I',
            v_tab
         );
      v_sep := ' UNION ALL ';
   END LOOP;

   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql;
END;$$;
```

it produces the right table schemaname.tablename, but..it doesn't recognize it because of the double quotes.

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado»
LINE 2:     FROM "vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado" UNI...
                 ^
```

how do I get rid of the double quotes??

if i use quote_indent()

```
select quote_ident(schemaname||'.'||tablename) as otra from pg_tables where schemaname = 'vigano' and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
```

it produces this:

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «"vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado"»
LINE 2:     FROM """vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado"""               ^
```

If I use quote_literal()

```
select quote_literal(schemaname||'.'||tablename) as otra from pg_tables where schemaname = 'vigano' and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
```

it produces:

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «'vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado'»
LINE 2:     FROM "'vigano.elcerro_elmolino_ver1920_soja_filtrado'" U...
                 ^
```

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres Dynamic Query Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639963/postgres-dynamic-query-function)

Comment: The code you have shown will **not** result in those values being quoted. Please show us the complete code of your function (or procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FORMAT()`, `%I` specifies an identifier, and is always quoted by double quotes...

Try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION yield_summary()
RETURNS TABLE (
   promedio double precision,
   minimo double precision,
   maximo double precision
) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  v_sql text := '';
  v_sep text := '';
  v_tab record;
BEGIN
  FOR v_tab IN
    SELECT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'vigano' AND pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
  LOOP
    v_sql := v_sql || v_sep || format(
      'SELECT round(avg(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) AS promedio, round(min(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) AS minimo, round(max(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) AS maximo 
       FROM %I.%I',
            v_tab.schemaname, v_tab.tablename
      );
    v_sep := ' UNION ALL ';
  END LOOP;
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_sql;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: thanks @Usagi Miyamoto, it works. The issue is that it produces a table with the three values (promedio, minimo, maximo) in the same column, inside brackets. Do you know how to produce a proper table with those column names? thanks

Comment: find the solution. i was doing `select yield_summary()` instead of `select * from yield_summary()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass schema name and table name as a single value to `format()`. Select two columns and pass two parameters.

```
FOR v_tab IN
  select schemaname, tablename as otra from pg_tables where schemaname = 'vigano' and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$'
LOOP
  v_sql := v_sql || v_sep ||
     format(
        'select round(avg(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as promedio, round(min(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as minimo, round(max(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as maximo 
         FROM %I.%I', 
         v_tab.schemaname, v_tab.tablename
     );
  v_sep := ' UNION ALL ';
END LOOP;
```

The way you used it, makes the `format()` function "think" that it's a **single** identifier that contains a `.` - which would require quoting.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you can simplify your code and get rid of the FOR loop completely:

```
select string_agg(
         format('select round(avg(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as promedio, round(min(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as minimo, round(max(masa_de_re)::numeric,3) as maximo 
                 FROM %I.%I', 
                 schemaname, tablename), ' UNION ALL ')
   into v_sql                      
from pg_tables 
where schemaname = 'vigano' 
and pg_tables.tablename ~ 'ver1920_soja_filtrado$';

return query 
  execute v_sql;
```

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I was trying your second approach. it throw the next error `ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «return»
LINE 9: return query 
        ^`